# Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как исправить код что бы он работал?
Выдаёт ошибку `Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>`

```
var range = $('.leftSide__grade__slide input[type="range"]')
range.on('change', function() {
    if(parseInt(range.val()) ++){
        console.log(1)
    }
})
```

Comment: А что Вы, собственно, хотите сделать?

Comment: Чтобы при увеличения значения ползунка выводилось в консоль 1 а при уменьшение 2. Те ++ и -- но выдаёт ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ну как вариант:**

```js
var $val = $("input[type='range']").val();

$("input[type='range']").on("change", function() {
  if (+$(this).val() > $val) {
    console.log("Значение увеличилось");
  } else {
    console.log("Значение уменьшилось");
  }
  $val = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" />
```